# SQL Server create rows from custom delimited text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I am to calculate of CO2 emissions for flight itineraries. A flight itinerary can consist of 1 hop like DXB/CDG, or ABJ/ADD/BKK/KUL/ADD/ABJ which would be 5 hops. My challenge is I need to break the itinerary information to individual flight information as the CO2 emission is calculated per flight:

**Source**: `ABJ/ADD/BKK/KUL/ADD/ABJ`

And convert it to:

[image]

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

To get your expected results, you can create a function which will split your string into rows using supplied delimiters. After that, you can make further adjustment or apply changes on returned data based on your requirement.

**Step-1:** Create the function

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[splitstring] ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) ,@Delimiter VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS @returnList TABLE ([Word] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @pos INT
    DECLARE @RN INT = 1

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @stringToSplit) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @stringToSplit)  
        SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

        INSERT INTO @returnList([Word],RN)
        SELECT @name,@RN

        SET @RN = @RN + 1

        SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
    END

    INSERT INTO @returnList([Word],RN)
    SELECT @stringToSplit,@RN

RETURN
END
```

**Step-2:** Achieve required data using that function

```
SELECT A.Word+'/'+B.Word FROM
(
    SELECT Word,RN 
    FROM [dbo].[splitstring]('ABJ/ADD/BKK/KUL/ADD/ABJ','/') 
) A
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Word,RN 
    FROM [dbo].[splitstring]('ABJ/ADD/BKK/KUL/ADD/ABJ','/')
)B ON A.RN = B.RN-1
```

Output will be-

```
ABJ/ADD
ADD/BKK
BKK/KUL
KUL/ADD
ADD/ABJ
```

Comment: A string splitter relying on a `WHILE` loop? Seriously? This is - uhm - slow and outdated...

Comment: This is a great solution. Thanks for the great help

Comment: Thanks @mkRabbani, I have managed to solve the problem using this function. I got to use a hybrid of your solution and the one by Shnugo's below to populate a table with all distinct routes, and then compute the emissions by passing the itinerary code to the function

Comment: @mkRabbani This answer is not guaranteed to return the correct order (due to `order by (select null)` and it is very slow...

Comment: @Robert It is your choice - of course - what you do, but I would not recommend this function...

Comment: @Shnugo, As there are no index applied and data is coming from a one column temporary table, the select statement should always return data in the original order always and I have given this solution from my practical implementation of data processing. But as there are no documentation of guaranteed data ordering from a select statement without using ORDER BY clause, I hands up to you and accepting your question/logic. Anyway, I am now transfer the Row_Number generation part to the function and every time the order should same now without any confusion. Tanks for your challenge on Ordering.

Comment: @Robert, as Shugo challenged the ordering option of data, I have made small changes to the Split function and added the row number generation part to the function now. The data order will be always same now without any doubt. (Note: I have the previous implementation on my similar static data for a long time and I never faced any ordering issue. But as no guaranteed documentation is there, please change your process according to the new changes.) Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @mkRabbani Well done, it is much better anyways to include the ordinal index to the splitter. But the function itself remains a dinosaur...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this approach:

```
DECLARE  @fligth VARCHAR(100)='ABJ/ADD/BKK/KUL/ADD/ABJ';

WITH Casted(flightXML) AS
    (SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@fligth,'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML))
,Tally(Nmbr) AS 
    (SELECT TOP((SELECT flightXML.value('count(/x)','int') FROM Casted)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values)
SELECT flightXML.value('(/x[sql:column("Nmbr")]/text())[1]','varchar(10)') AS FromAirport
      ,flightXML.value('(/x[sql:column("Nmbr")+1]/text())[1]','varchar(10)') AS ToAirport
FROM Casted
CROSS JOIN Tally
WHERE flightXML.value('(/x[sql:column("Nmbr")+1]/text())[1]','varchar(10)') IS NOT NULL;
```

The idea:

We transform the delimited string to XML by replacing the delimiters with tags. So we get

```
<x>ABJ</x>
<x>ADD</x>
<x>BKK</x>
<x>KUL</x>
<x>ADD</x>
<x>ABJ</x>
```

Now XQuery allows as to retrieve values by their positions. Therefore the second CTE creates a *tally-on-the-fly*. It will return running numbers from to n, where n is the count of stops in your string.

The final query will use `sql:column()` to introduce the tally-number into the XQuery. You can read it as *Find the `<x>` at position `Nmbr` and return its content. And now find the `<x>` at position `Nmbr+1`.*

Comment: I had not given this thought either, it is a great solution to break it down without requiring a function